# Outlook Contextual add-in: Rules Collection Not Working

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am implementing Contextual add-in and have applied the rules as below.

```
 <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" PropertyName="SenderSMTPAddress" RegExName="addressMatches" RegExValue="xxxx@.onmicrosoft.com" IgnoreCase="true" />
  <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" RegExName="OrderNumber" RegExValue="someText" PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" Highlight="all" IgnoreCase="true"/>
 </Rule>
```

I want to highlight the matching text only if it is coming from the specific sender address, hence the SenderSMTPAddress rule.

However once the add-in is added, the matching text in the email body is not highlighted. Is there anything wrong with the Rule ?

If I remove the SMTPAddess rule, the matching text is highlighted and add-in works as expected.

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue in the Outlook web client (OWA) or the native desktop Outlook client?

Comment: In OWA while sideloading the add-in.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue regarding SenderSMTPAddress rule in contextual add-ins. It has been put on our backlog. We unfortunately have no timelines to share at this point

Comment: Hi, Is it a bug ? Any work around to minimize this ? I don't want to invoke the add-in on emails from all senders. I only need to be activated only on emails from specific address.